# google places listings migration to google plus business

Tags: google-maps, google-plus, google-places

I have a business listing under a google places account.

Google said that we can still editing the business using the same google places account.

The business isn't showing up anymore at google maps, can't find it, which is correct because the listing is showing 0 impressions/actions.

What should I do?
Is there a kind of migration in order to create a google+ page? How? Can't find it.
Simply ignore that listing and start fresh at google+ for business?

The information I find over the internet is vary confused.

What you say?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple paths to completing this task. The best one is likely to use the [Google Places dashboard](http://www.google.com/local/add/businessCenter)

You can use that tool to add or edit business listing, to verify ownership, and to enable the business to appear on maps.

Additionally, you can [create a Google+ Page](https://plus.google.com/pages/create) for your business, which helps for both Google+ users in Google+ Local as well as for maps. Choose the **Local Business or Place** option.

Answer (score 0):

You Can visit Google Places dashboard by creating an Account.
There are many other online business directories where you can list your business. The best online business directory [Here](http://www.dexberry.com/)